# SQL keyword searching with full- and part-strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, keyword

Looking for a short string, e.g. `air`, with SQL commands often returns datasets which contain words where the short string is part of, e.g. `airline`. Is there a recommendable way to exclude results which are caused by `airline` only?

Example: Accept everything with `air` except for `airline`

> String 1: "The air is fresh."
>
> String 2: "The airline ticket is fair."
>
> String 3: "The airline has 30 planes."

The command should return String 1 and 2 only.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Look into using full text search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for it: replace the undesired `airplane` with empty string.

```
select STRINGS from TABLE where replace(STRINGS,'airplane','') like '%air%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where RESULT like '%air%' AND RESULT <> 'airline'
```

Comment: This suggestion does not exclude String 3 as that string consists of more than 'airline' only.